# Stripe Flutter : "error: no suitable constructor found for ReadableMap(HashMap<Object,Object>)"

Tags: java, android, flutter, stripe-payments, build.gradle

I want to implement Stripe to my Application.

To do this, I have this pattern :

The suer click on a product, it's linked to the BackEnd, who generate a PaymentIntent and send it to the FrontEnd. When my Front receive the Intent, he's asking card, numbers, and data to request Stripe's API.

BUT

After creating my Front, I have an issue and I can't compile my code...

SO, this is how my application is made :

in main.dart :

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  /// Initialize Stripe
  Stripe.publishableKey = "**********************************************";

.....
.....
.....
}
```

in product.dart (the products page) :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';

import '../../services/api.dart';

class ProductsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProductsPage> createState() => _ProductsPageState();
}

class _ProductsPageState extends State<ProductsPage> {
  String? intentPayment;
  final productsList = [
    {
      "name": "Abonnement 30 jours",
      "description": "Abonnement test 30 jours",
      "price": 100,
      "duree": "30"
    },
    {
      "name": "Abonnement 60 jours",
      "description": "",
      "price": 180,
      "duree": "60"
    },
    {
      "name": "Abonnement 90 jours",
      "description": "Abonnement test 30 jours",
      "price": 250,
      "duree": "90"
    },
  ];

  Future<void> makePayment(product) async {
    try {
      intentPayment = await Api.getIntent(product);
      await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        paymentIntentClientSecret: intentPayment!,
        // applePay: const PaymentSheetApplePay(merchantCountryCode: 'FR'),
        // googlePay: const PaymentSheetGooglePay(merchantCountryCode: 'FR'),
        style: ThemeMode.dark,
        merchantDisplayName: 'JobMe Test',
      ));
      displayPaymentSheet();
    } catch (e) {
      print("exception: $e");
    }
  }

  displayPaymentSheet() async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then(((value) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                  content: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: const [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.check_circle,
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          Text("Paiement effectué avec succès.")
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ));

        intentPayment = null;
      }));
    } on StripeException catch (e) {
      print("Stripe Exception: $e");
    } catch (e) {
      print("exception: $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await makePayment(productsList[0]);
                      },
                      child: const Text("Abonnement 1 mois. 100€")),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await makePayment(productsList[1]);
                      },
                      child: const Text("Abonnement 2 mois. 180€")),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await makePayment(productsList[2]);
                      },
                      child: const Text("Abonnement 3 mois. 250€")),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

And this is the error I get when I try to run the application :

```
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-5.1.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\bridge\WritableNativeMap.java:22: error: no suitable constructor found for ReadableMap(HashMap<Object,Object>)

        super(new HashMap<>());
        ^
    constructor ReadableMap.ReadableMap(JSONObject) is not applicable      (argument mismatch; HashMap<Object,Object> cannot be converted to JSONObject)
    constructor ReadableMap.ReadableMap(Map<String,Object>) is not applicable      (argument mismatch; HashMap<Object,Object> cannot be converted to Map<String,Object>)
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:Execution failed for task ':stripe_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

(My flutter doctor -v is fine, and I've already try to remove the build folder. I also switched FlutterActivity() to FlutterFragmentActivity() in MainActivity.kt)

Please help :)

Comment: Could you please share the full stackstrace error, that could help understanding the root issue. Where is that constructor function called from?
Between, you can take a look at this Flutter example app as a complete working sample project:
https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/tree/main/example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found how to solve this issue.

I downgraded the flutter_stripe version from 5.1.0 to 4.0.0 and it's working perfectly fine now !

Answer (score 8):

Update the gradle version at
`android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip
```

and update build gradle of root level to 7.2.1 at `android/build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
```